# How to write lodash function in es6 style?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have old lodash function:

```
  data = _.reject(items, function(i) {
    return i.id == id;
  })
```

how to write it in es6 way?

```
  data = _.reject(items, i => {
    return i.id == id;
  })
```

got error

Comment: Which error did you get? Also, `function() {...}` is no less ES6 than arrow functions are. Arrow functions merely provide more options.

Comment: If you're going to return the result of an expression immediately, you can leave off the `{` `}` brackets (and the `return`)

Comment: Also, single-letter variable names aren't such a great idea, especially `i` when `i` isn't referring to a counter of some sort

Comment: @CertainPerformance: "If you're going to return the result of an expression immediately, you can leave off the { } brackets" ... and `return`. You can't keep `return` if going braceless (`return` is a statement, braceless arrow function only accepts an expression)

Comment: `got error` - throwing it out there, you're using Internet Exploder or an early (pre 4.2?) version of nodejs - how did I go? ... by the way, `data = _.reject(items, i => i.id == id);` would be the most compact version using arrow notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just not use lodash in this case, depending on what your question actually is:

```
const items = [2, 3, 88, 99]

const smallItems = items.filter(item => item < 50)

console.log(smallItems) // 2, 3 // High numbers are rejected
```

Or... you could write up your own reject in ES6 depending on your needs

```
// Create function once 
const reject = (data, predicate) => data.filter(item => !predicate(item))

// Use elsewhere
const items = [2, 3, 88, 99]
const smallItems = reject(items, item => item > 50)    
console.log(smallItems)
```